# How to have Windows 10 Task Scheduler run Python script?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, windows-10, scheduled-tasks

I am unable to get Windows 10 Task Scheduler to run a Python script. I have set the scheduler to run the python.exe program, and I passed in the .py script I want to run as an argument, but confusingly it is not working. The Python script is a working script.

Could someone tell me what they think I might be doing wrong?

Apparently windows tasks are exported as xml files. Here is the Windows task.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task" version="1.4">
    <RegistrationInfo>
        <Date>2017-09-07T16:03:54.7948519</Date>
        <Author>LAPTOP-K2677IHO\keith</Author>
        <Description>Runs python script to collect rs stock data.</Description>
        <URI>\CollectRSStockData</URI>
    </RegistrationInfo>
    <Triggers>
        <CalendarTrigger>
            <StartBoundary>2017-09-07T16:00:32</StartBoundary>
            <Enabled>true</Enabled>
            <ScheduleByDay>
                <DaysInterval>1</DaysInterval>
            </ScheduleByDay>
        </CalendarTrigger>
    </Triggers>
    <Principals>
        <Principal id="Author">
            <UserId>S-1-5-21-296473394-3322303487-2558410130-1001</UserId>
            <LogonType>InteractiveToken</LogonType>
            <RunLevel>LeastPrivilege</RunLevel>
        </Principal>
    </Principals>
    <Settings>
        <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
        <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>true</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
        <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>false</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
        <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
        <StartWhenAvailable>false</StartWhenAvailable>
        <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
        <IdleSettings>
            <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
            <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
        </IdleSettings>
        <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
        <Enabled>true</Enabled>
        <Hidden>false</Hidden>
        <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
        <DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>false</DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>
        <UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>true</UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>
        <WakeToRun>true</WakeToRun>
        <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT72H</ExecutionTimeLimit>
        <Priority>7</Priority>
    </Settings>
    <Actions Context="Author">
        <Exec>
            <Command>"C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe"</Command>
            <Arguments>"C:\Users\keith\Documents\scripts\python.scripts\rsstocks\main.py"</Arguments>
        </Exec>
    </Actions>
</Task>
```

Comment: Can you provide more information about the task you have created?

Comment: @Jack I updated with the task file as xml.

Comment: It's set to run interactive. Is the user logged on in an interactive session? If yes, when it fails to run is there a useful status code or just 1? Maybe Python is exiting on an error. Are you using logging or at least redirecting `sys.stderr` to a file to log exceptions? If it's failing on an error, maybe it's that the script needs a particular working directory instead of "%SystemRoot%\System32" -- though if it's written well it shouldn't.